# CORS the easyway

Tags: angularjs, cors, laravel-5

I'm trying to 'put' data to my Laravel 5 server running on localhost from a webpage thats is also served localhost, but from other server software (nodejs). But im getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/data/. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
```

The code that creates the put request is angularjs and looks like this:

```
 return $http.put("http://localhost:8888/data/", { obj1: a, obj2: b });
```

What is the simplest way to get around CORS? Security  is no issue.
Using the postman plug-in in chrome I'm able to send the put request.

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is my laravel setup for cors.

I've created an http.php config file with this settings:

```
return [
    'cors' => [
        'origin' => '*',
        'methods' => 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
        'headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authentication-Token',
    ],
];
```

Run this code somewhere on application startup:

```
if ( ! App::runningInConsole()) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . Config::get('http.cors.origin'));
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); // to be honest i've never used this option, but it looks like you'll need it

    // handle preflight requests
    App::before(function() {
        if (Request::getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            return new Response('', 200, [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => Config::get('http.cors.methods'),
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => Config::get('http.cors.headers'),
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is it appropriate to insert the last part of your code?

Comment: In your service provider if you got one (Laravel 5), or simply in the start/global.php file (Laravel 4).

Comment: @M K Sorry for my ignorance, but this is by very first php code. Would RouteServiceProvider.php be a good place to place the code? Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: Yes, create a method like "enableCors", put the code inside it and call it inside your service provider, before the registration of your application routes.

Comment: Don't forget to create the config file, or hard code the header options. It should then work right away.

Answer (score 1):

**Postman doesn't use CORS.**

To enable CORS (in the client side) add : `{ withCredentials: true }` in your put options :

```
 return $http.put("http://localhost:8888/data/", { obj1: a, obj2: b }, { withCredentials: true });
```

**Note:** Depending on your server application, you may enable them in the server side too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be an Angular problem. You should try enabling CORS on the PHP with:

```
// Enable CORS 
// In production, replace * with http://yourdomain.com 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```